# Daily push notification when the app is closed in android java

Tags: java, android, push-notification

Daily push notification when the app is closed in android java !

Hello guys , any help !
its working only when my app is opened
this is the code i'm using

How to Send a notification when the Android app is closed

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <receiver android:name=".dailyNotification.Notification_reciever"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

this is the reciever class

**Notification_reciever.java**

```
public class Notification_reciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "10001" ;
private final static String default_notification_channel_id = "default" ;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent repeating_intent =new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    repeating_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,100,repeating_intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,
            default_notification_channel_id )
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable. ic_launcher_foreground )
            .setContentTitle("Notification 1")
            .setContentText("Hello");
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context. NOTIFICATION_SERVICE ) ;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION. SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES. O ) {
        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes. CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION )
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM )
                .build() ;
        int importance = NotificationManager. IMPORTANCE_HIGH ;
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new
                NotificationChannel( NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID , "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME" , importance) ;
        notificationChannel.enableLights( true ) ;
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color. RED ) ;
        notificationChannel.enableVibration( true ) ;
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern( new long []{ 100 , 200 , 300 , 400 , 500 , 400 , 300 , 200 , 400 }) ;
        mBuilder.setChannelId( NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID ) ;
        assert mNotificationManager != null;
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel) ;
    }
    assert mNotificationManager != null;
    mNotificationManager.notify(( int ) System. currentTimeMillis (), mBuilder.build()) ;


   }
}
```

**Setup Alarm :**

```
    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,22);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,20);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Notification_reciever.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),100,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
```

Comment: You have already done the implementation, Can you specify what output you got, and is there any error post the logcat as well would be helpful.

Comment: all things going well otherwise when the app is closed

Comment: Instead of run via android studio try build the APK (Build --> Build APK) and test it.

Comment: no bro its not working :(

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using AlarmManger and you can watch this video to learn how to use AlarmManger [Display Android notification at a particular time with Alarm Manager](https://youtu.be/nl-dheVpt8o)

I hope this helps you and you can put 86400 Seconds to display after 24 hour